# How to develop a Java based Webhook to get notification of new Mails from Office 365?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, office365, webhooks, office365api

We do have a scenario where  we need to receive a push notification when a user receives email on Office 365 Outlook. I’ve found the [following article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458791%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) but it was very though for me to figure out what APIs to use in order to develop the same functionality on Java. Can you also elaborate if we need to use the Push notification or Streaming notifications in our case.

Answer (score 0):

See the link below with sample C# code. The Java code is almost identical.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458792(v=exchg.150).aspx

For Java use the ews-java-api library below
https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api

As for streaming vs push they can both fulfil your usecase. I prefer streaming (implemented through long polling) since it's simpler to use. (push requires a public listener endpoint)